# Python to Arduino with pyserial, all of a sudden freezes with no errors

Tags: python, serialization, arduino, pygame

Hello there people of the internet, my team and I are running into an issue with this python code that sends a byte array of 37 characters to an arduino. The arduino controls 4 dc motors and 4 180 degree servos so we send the control data down to it via pyserial. We are using two logitech extreme 3d pro joysticks (reference link below) connected to the computer via usb. Using pygame the input is converted to PWM data that is sent to the arduino (already explained how that is done a few sentences ago). Our issue is that the code works perfectly on a MacOS machine, and when we attempt to run it on either a windows or linux machine (the laptop we will be using will have linux installed we just tested windows to see if it would work) it works for a few short seconds then freezes. When I test this code without the 4 dc motors and 4 servos attached (can't bring them home with me) it works perfectly on all os's, my colleague keeps telling me it's a programming issue but I can't seem to find it. I have attached all of the code below, if you have any questions please let me know.

Python Code

```
import pygame
import numpy as np
import serial

# function to map servo/motor data dependent on joystick input
def map(joy, min, max, omin, omax):
    return float((((joy - min) * (omax - omin)) / (max - min)) + omin)


# same as above but used for the corner values of the joystick
def mapc(joy1, joy2, min1, max1, min2, max2, omin, omax):
    return float((((((joy1 - min1) * (omax - omin)) / (max1 - min1)) + omin) + ((((joy2 - min2) * (omax - omin)) / (max2 - min2)) + omin)) / 2)

# dum1 = input("1: ")

class JoyStickClass:
    # set up the joysticks and arduino
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.joystick.init()

        self.Joy1 = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
        self.Joy2 = pygame.joystick.Joystick(1)
        self.Joy1.init()
        self.Joy2.init()

        self.M1_Data = 1500
        self.M2_Data = 1500
        self.M3_Data = 1500
        self.S1_Data = 1500
        self.S2_Data = 1500
        self.S3_Data = 1500
        self.S4_Data = 1500
        self.lights = 0

        # port = str(input("Enter com port (Windows: COM, MacOS: usual crap:) : "))
        self.ard1 = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1434201', 115200, timeout = 0.01)

        self.startMarker = '<'
        self.endMarker = '\n'
        self.dividingmarker = ','

        self.Timer = 0

    # read the data from the joysticks and store them in their variables
    def JoyRead(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            self.Joy1X = self.Joy1.get_axis(0)
            self.Joy1Y = self.Joy1.get_axis(1)

            self.Joy1B1 = self.Joy1.get_button(0)
            self.Joy1B6 = self.Joy1.get_button(5)
            self.Joy1B7 = self.Joy1.get_button(6)
            self.Joy1B8 = self.Joy1.get_button(7)
            self.Joy1B3 = self.Joy1.get_button(2)

            self.Joy2X = self.Joy2.get_axis(0)
            self.Joy2Y = self.Joy2.get_axis(1)

            self.Joy2B1 = self.Joy2.get_button(0)
            self.Joy2B3 = self.Joy2.get_button(2)
            self.Joy2B5 = self.Joy2.get_button(4)

            self.Joy1H = self.Joy1.get_hat(0)
    garbo = 1500
    # Convert the data read from the joysticks to useful motor and servo data
    def JoyConv(self):
        self.Timer = self.Timer + 1 

# Motor crap
        x= self.Joy1X * 1
        y=self.Joy1Y * 1
        # Deadzones
        if x > -.1 and x < .1:
            x = 0
        if y > -.1 and y < .1:
            y = 0
        tamp = map(abs(y),0,1,500,0)
        # //preturn

        pT = map(x,-1,1,-tamp,tamp)
        lM = map(y, -1, 1, 1000, 2000)
        rM = map(y, -1, 1, 1000, 2000)
        # //Take the amplitude of the motors
        lMAmp = round(1500-lM)
        lMAmp -= pT
        lM = 1500 - lMAmp
        rMAmp = round(1500-rM)
        rMAmp += pT
        rM = 1500 - rMAmp
        self.M1_Data = round(lM)
        self.M2_Data = round(rM)

#Up Down
        if self.Joy1B7 == 1 and self.Joy1B8 == 0:
            self.M3_Data = 1000
        elif self.Joy1B8 == 1 and self.Joy1B7 == 0:
            self.M3_Data = 2000
        else:
            self.M3_Data = 1500

        self.S2_Data = round(map(self.Joy2X, 1, -1, 800, 2200))

# ArmTIlt
        if round(map(self.Joy2Y, -1, 1, 1000, 2000)) > 1600 and self.S1_Data < 2200 and self.Timer % 50 == 0:
            self.S1_Data = self.S1_Data + 7
        elif round(map(self.Joy2Y, -1, 1, 1000, 2000)) < 1400 and self.S1_Data > 1000 and self.Timer % 50 == 0:
            self.S1_Data = self.S1_Data - 7
        else:
            self.S1_Data = self.S1_Data


        if self.Joy2B1 == 1:
            self.S3_Data = 2000
        else:
            self.S3_Data = 1000

# Camera
        if self.Joy1H == (0, -1) and self.S4_Data <= 2200 and self.Timer % 100 == 0:
            self.S4_Data = self.S4_Data + 15
        elif self.Joy1H == (0, 1) and self.S4_Data >= 1000 and self.Timer % 100 == 0:
            self.S4_Data = self.S4_Data - 15
        else:
            self.S4_Data = self.S4_Data

# lights
        if self.Joy1H == (1, 0):
            self.lights = 1
        elif self.Joy1H == (-1, 0):
            self.lights = 0
        else:
            self.lights = self.lights

    # Send the data to the arduino
    def send_to_arduino(self):
        Sending_Data1 = str(self.M1_Data)
        Sending_Data1 += self.dividingmarker
        Sending_Data1 += str(self.M2_Data)
        Sending_Data1 += self.dividingmarker
        Sending_Data1 += str(self.M3_Data)
        Sending_Data1 += self.dividingmarker
        Sending_Data1 += str(self.S1_Data)
        Sending_Data1 += self.dividingmarker
        Sending_Data1 += str(self.S2_Data)
        Sending_Data1 += self.dividingmarker
        Sending_Data1 += str(self.S3_Data)
        Sending_Data1 += self.dividingmarker
        Sending_Data1 += str(self.S4_Data)
        Sending_Data1 += self.dividingmarker
        Sending_Data1 += str(self.lights)
        Sending_Data1 += self.endMarker

        Sending_Data_ByteArray1 = bytearray(Sending_Data1, 'ascii')
        # print()
        if self.ard1.inWaiting():
            self.ard1.flush()
            self.ard1.write(Sending_Data_ByteArray1)
            data = self.ard1.readline()
            print(data, len(Sending_Data_ByteArray1))
            # self.ard1.flush()

class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.joy = JoyStickClass()
    def run(self):
        self.joy.JoyRead()
        self.joy.JoyConv()
        self.joy.send_to_arduino()

main = MainClass()
while 1==1:
    main.run()
```

Arduino Code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo M1;
Servo M2;
Servo M3;
Servo M4;
Servo S1;
Servo S2;
Servo S3;
Servo S4;

int VA = 0; //1000-2000
int VB = 0; //1000-2000
int VC = 0; //1000-2000
int VD = 0; //1000-2000
int VE = 0; //1000-2000
int VF = 0; //1000-2000
int VG = 0; //1000-2000
int VH = 0; //1000-2000
int VI = 0; //1 or 0

int Lights = 13;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  pinMode(Lights, OUTPUT);
  M1.attach(22);
  M2.attach(23);
  M3.attach(24);
  M4.attach(25);
  S1.attach(30);
  S2.attach(34);
  S3.attach(38);
  S4.attach(42);
}

void SerialEvent()
{
  char characterBuf[39];  //stores incoming
  int incomingLength = 0; //stores incoming length
  char *token;            //token for converting byte array to string array
  int counterNum = 1;
  //1503,1503,1500,1503,1523,1000,1500,0

  if (Serial.available()) {
    //    Serial.println("1");
    incomingLength = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', characterBuf, 50);    //calculate length of byte array
    token = strtok(characterBuf, ",");  //convert to string
    VA = atoi(token);
    //    Serial.println(token);
    while (token != NULL) {   //if token doesnt find another comma it goes back to beginning

      token = strtok(NULL, ",");  //changes token to a string def of NULL
      //      Serial.println(token);

      switch (counterNum) {
        case 1:
          VB = atoi(token);
          break;

        case 2:
          VC = atoi(token);
          break;

        case 3:
          VD = atoi(token);
          break;

        case 4:
          VE = atoi(token);
          break;

        case 5:
          VF = atoi(token);
          break;

        case 6:
          VG = atoi(token);
          break;

        case 7:
          VH = atoi(token);
          break;

        case 8:
          VI = atoi(token);
          break;
      }
      counterNum++;
    }
  }
}
void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available()) {
    SerialEvent();

    M1.writeMicroseconds(VA);
    M2.writeMicroseconds(VB);
    M3.writeMicroseconds(VC);
    M4.writeMicroseconds(VD);
    S1.writeMicroseconds(VE);
    S2.writeMicroseconds(VF);
    S3.writeMicroseconds(VG);
    S4.writeMicroseconds(VH);

    if (VI == 1) {
      digitalWrite(Lights, HIGH);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(Lights, LOW);
    }
  }
  Serial.print("M1: ");
  Serial.print(VA);
  Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("M2: ");
  Serial.print(VB);
  Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("M3: ");
  Serial.print(VC);
  Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("M4: ");
  Serial.print(VC);
  Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("S1: ");
  Serial.print(VD);
  Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("S2: ");
  Serial.print(VE);
  Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("S3: ");
  Serial.print(VF);
  Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("S4: ");
  Serial.print(VG);
  Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print("Lights: ");
  Serial.print(VH);
  Serial.println();
}
```

please excuse any formatting errors, I have been working on this problem for the last 48 hours and I didn't have time to check it for those.

Also reference link to the joysticks:

```
https://www.amazon.com/Extreme-3D-Pro-Joystick-Windows/dp/B00009OY9U/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1MQ474EU5M3KK&dchild=1&keywords=logitech+extreme+3d+pro+joystick&qid=1615092807&sprefix=logitech+extreme+%2Caps%2C164&sr=8-1
```

reference links to both the servos and the motors:

Servos:

```
https://www.savoxusa.com/products/savsw1210sg-waterproof-coreless-digital
```

Motors:

```
http://aquaphoton.net/aquaphoton/?product=seabotix-thruster-btd150
```

Any other questions let me know

Answer (score 0):

By switching the serial.flush to the arduino side it fixed the problem.